# How to know the performance of competitors bidding for my brand keywords?

Tags: google-ads

For my brandname "XYZ", few competitors are bidding on Adwords. I want to know, their performance such as 
1. CTR for their bidding 
2. Their conv.rate 
3. clicks

If this is not possible, any other parameters apart form whats mentioned on Adowrds' auction insight.